# Creating a "normalized share over time" plot in R

Tags: r, graph

I'm interested in making a plot that is normalized and can trend share over time. Here is an example:

(http://stevecoast.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/normalised-phone-share2-001.jpg)

The data I am using is just 2 factors (1,0), so there would be two colors. There are 3178 observations in total. I'm not sure if there is a function that will allow me to keep the data in this form or transformation will be required.

```
set.seed(124)
variableValue <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)
set.seed(124)
timePeriod <-sort(sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace=TRUE))
sort(timePeriod)
data<-data.frame(variableValue,timePeriod)
data
```

I figured ggplot is the best way to go, but I'm pretty lost as to where to start.

Any advice would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Start with sharing (or simulating) data to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: Do you really have a categorical variable for your x-axis? Not a date or time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want `variableValue` treated categorically, we'll first convert it to a factor:

```
data$variableValue = factor(data$variableValue)
```

You can do a lot of data manipulation inside ggplot, but I prefer to do it beforehand for better transparency.

```
library(dplyr)
dat_summ = data %>% group_by(timePeriod) %>%
    mutate(n_time = n()) %>%
    group_by(timePeriod, variableValue) %>%
    summarize(proportion = n() / first(n_time))
```

This makes a data frame with one row per variableValue per timePeriod, and a proportion column for each: exactly what we want to plot.

```
ggplot(dat_summ, aes(x = timePeriod, y = proportion,
                     fill = variableValue, group = variableValue)) +
    geom_area() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Then we can plot. We specify the variables that get mapped to x and y axes and fill color, and since we have a categorical variable on the x-axis we need to specify a `group` definition to "connect the dots". `geom_area` is a filled-in area graph, it's default will stack the areas on top of each other like we want. To be fancy, I specify to use percent scales on the y-axis---this whole line could be omitted otherwise.

[image]

Comment: After copying and pasting your code - I keep getting an error: Variable 'n_total' not found.....Am I missing a package?

Comment: @MarkRomano no, sorry. I renamed `n_total` to `n_time` but didn't make the change both places it showed up. Should work now.

Comment: Gotcha....I'm not too familiar with dplyr package (though I should!) and thought maybe it was a special keyword. Worked like a charm, thanks!